# SQL Server - How many rows have been inserted into a table while a query is running?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a cleansing script that has 10 unions and results in, more or less, 1.2 billion rows (I'm re-executing this script including some missing fields, so I know and expect this number at the end of the execution).

I'm inserting this cleaned data into a new table (X). I've made some researches and I found this query from MS site:

```
    -- Do not lock anything, and do not get held up by any locks.
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    -- Quickly get row counts.
    SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Schema]
        , OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Table]
        , i.name AS [Index]
        , p.partition_number
        , p.rows AS [Row Count]
        , i.type_desc AS [Index Type]
    FROM sys.partitions p
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON p.object_id = i.object_id
                             AND p.index_id = i.index_id
    WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) != 'sys'
    ORDER BY [Schema], [Table], [Index]
```

And I found out that my Row Count is 0 and Index Type is HEAP for this X table.
My query is running around 7 hours. I think it could be done in a day.
I also tried to select top 1, select count(*), count(1), writing with (nolock) and none of these queries ran.

Is this right? SQL should have loaded some data into this new table, right?
Anyone has any idea to help me figure it out if something went wrong during this query execution?

I just want to know if this query is really working, and I thought of looking data from this new table.

------edit--------

My select statement is a cleansing from a table named BSEG (from SAP). This table has more than 100 columns.

It is like this:

```
Select BUKRS, convert(datetime, BUDAT), convert(decimal(18,2), field3)...
into table a
from BSEG1

union

Select BUKRS, convert(datetime, BUDAT), convert(decimal(18,2), field3)...
from BSEG2

union (...)
```

I imported these data from a txt file (nvarchar 4000 - BCP). Maybe this could be slowing down the process?

Comment: If at all possible you should add a clustered index to your table. A heap with 1.2 billion rows is a nightmare.

Comment: wut? are you saying you execute an INSERT query and it inserted no rows? is that your question? show the INSERT statement then. otherwise , please clarify. i suspect your ten join result in a lot of work and no rows selected.

Comment: @SeanLange I have my "input" tables with clustered columnstores indexes.

Comment: @RicardoC It is a select into query. It is like "select cast(field A), cast(field B)... into X from A union select cast.... from B" and so on. I imported some .txt files, and I have to clean this data. Dates from these input tables are like "20160309" and I want to show this data as Datetime in this new table (this is just an example). So I want to know why can't I see any rows in this result table. Does select into statements doesn't show "in time" inserted data?

Comment: Using select into I don't think the table will exist in sys.partitions during the insert even using read uncommitted. 7 hours to read and write 1.2 billion rows sounds extreme to me.

Comment: @SeanLange it must be taking 7 hours because is calculating 1.2 billion row joins, this is time on reads, but likely 0 seconds on writes because the joins produce no rows as a result set. this is my guess.

Comment: @cotiovis you must show your SELECT INTO statement or we wont be able to help. Also, what Sean said.

Comment: Guys, there are no joins, only unions.

Comment: I updated the question with the select statement. My query finished after 10 hours. But I still have the doubt of how could I count the rows from my new table with the "cleaned" data from this select into query? I mean, after 1 hour of execution I could have, IDK, 2 millions rows at least in my new table? Does SQL Server put all the data at once all the rows are finished?

Comment: First step in optimising your query: use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. I assume `UNION` was not intentional

Comment: now that we know you are using BCP utility, use the output parameter to see the progress, and also you can use the the -h"ROWS_PER_BATCH = bb" option or -b batch_size, but do NOT use both. read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx for more info.

Comment: also, make sure you have no indices in the target table while importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you dont split your select into in  10 insert into?

first create the result table:

```
Select BUKRS, convert(datetime, BUDAT), convert(decimal(18,2), field3)...
into MyTable
from BSEG1
WHERE 1=0 -- this will do the trick
```

next

```
insert into MyTable
Select BUKRS, convert(datetime, BUDAT), convert(decimal(18,2), field3)...
from BSEG1

PRINT @@ROWCOUNT

insert into MyTable
Select BUKRS, convert(datetime, BUDAT), convert(decimal(18,2), field3)...
from BSEG2

PRINT @@ROWCOUNT

insert into (...)
```

in this way you should simply read the records in MyTable using:

```
select count(*) from MyTable with (nolock)
```

you can also put all the insert statements into a stored procedure if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this function will help? You can run it every `n` minutes to see how many rows are currently in the table.

```
EXEC sp_spaceused(db.schema.table)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16